# Android AsyncTask example and explanation

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I want to use an `AsyncTask` in my app, but I am having trouble finding a code snippet with a simple explanation of how things work. I just want something to help me get back up to speed quickly without having to wade through [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) or lots of Q&As again.

Comment: What is wrong with http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: also [Using AsyncTask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18898039/using-asynctask/18898105#18898105)

Comment: It was actually better in it's original form. Now, it looks too broad for SO. Your wanting to share and help is appreciated. [But even self-answer questions should adhere to SO guidelines](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261616/self-answer-questions-being-too-broad). The original Q&A was good just a dupe and there is nothing wrong with that. [See this meta post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265736/should-i-delete-my-question-if-it-is-marked-as-a-duplicate)

Answer (score 226, accepted):

`AsyncTask` is one of the easiest ways to implement parallelism in Android without having to deal with more complex methods like Threads. Though it offers a basic level of parallelism with the UI thread, it should not be used for longer operations (of, say, not more than 2 seconds).

AsyncTask has four methods

- `onPreExecute()`
- `doInBackground()`
- `onProgressUpdate()`
- `onPostExecute()`

where `doInBackground()` is the most important as it is where background computations are performed.

### Code:

Here is a skeletal code outline with explanations:

```
public class AsyncTaskTestActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);  

        // This starts the AsyncTask
        // Doesn't need to be in onCreate()
        new MyTask().execute("my string parameter");
    }

    // Here is the AsyncTask class:
    //
    // AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result>.
    //    Params – the type (Object/primitive) you pass to the AsyncTask from .execute() 
    //    Progress – the type that gets passed to onProgressUpdate()
    //    Result – the type returns from doInBackground()
    // Any of them can be String, Integer, Void, etc. 

    private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

        // Runs in UI before background thread is called
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            // Do something like display a progress bar
        }

        // This is run in a background thread
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            // get the string from params, which is an array
            String myString = params[0];

            // Do something that takes a long time, for example:
            for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {

                // Do things

                // Call this to update your progress
                publishProgress(i);
            }

            return "this string is passed to onPostExecute";
        }

        // This is called from background thread but runs in UI
        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);

            // Do things like update the progress bar
        }

        // This runs in UI when background thread finishes
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            // Do things like hide the progress bar or change a TextView
        }
    }
}
```

### Flow Diagram:

Here is a diagram to help explain where all the parameters and types are going:

[image]

### Other helpful links:

- [What arguments are passed into AsyncTask<arg1, arg2, arg3>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6053602/what-arguments-are-passed-into-asynctaskarg1-arg2-arg3)
- [Slidenerd Android AsyncTask Tutorial: Android Tutorial For Beginners](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V4q0sTIntsk)
- [Understanding AsyncTask – Once and Forever](http://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2012/03/17/understanding-asynctask-once-and-forever/)
- [Dealing with AsyncTask and Screen Orientation](http://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2013/05/10/dealing-with-asynctask-and-screen-orientation/)
- [How to pass multiple parameters to AsynkTask](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12069670/3681880)
- [how to pass in two different data types to AsyncTask, Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17989914/how-to-pass-in-two-different-data-types-to-asynctask-android)

Comment: very cool man, the documentation as usually is not there I've been using without really knowing why I had do it that way.

Comment: Visualizing the data flow to constructor will make the image more beautiful!