# Inserting Data into MySQL from Android

Tags: php, android, mysql

I am unable to insert data into my MySQL database. And I also have send reply back to Android Module to show if the data is saved or not.

PHP code:

```
   $id = $_POST['Id'];
        $name = $_POST['Name'];
        $email = $_POST['Email'];

        $con = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test", "root", "");

        $query = "Insert into record values ('$id','$name','$email')";
        //$query = "Select * from record";
        $result = $con->query($query);
```

And Android code:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_new);

    final EditText Id = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    final String id = Id.getText().toString();
    final EditText Name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    final String name = Name.getText().toString();
    final EditText Email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    final String email = Id.getText().toString();

    Button SavePush = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    SavePush.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.3.2:8080/insert.php");

            try{

                ArrayList NameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(3);
                NameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Id",id));
                NameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Name", name));
                NameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Email", email));

                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(NameValuePairs));
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
            }catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: you can't communicate with internet in UI thread , you must use `Thread`  or `AsyncTask` , read your logcat to get usefull data , you must got `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException` for more info about that read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception

Comment: The problem is in insert into statement, table names are missing

Comment: You don't seem to have tested the PDO query for success - see the manual for the return values. Also, you have a SQL injection hole here, so if you don't want to get hacked, switch to prepared statements.

Comment: You can respond to the app using XML, JSON or just an HTTP response code. That would be something you could research and try? There are sure to be examples out there.

Comment: @shayanpourvatan Can you show me how to do that. I need to insert data and retrieve

Comment: @halfer I tested my PDO locally via form through HTML Post.
I am learning it, Thanks i will surely look into SQL injections :)

Comment: i solved following problem using OKHttp & getting response on UIthread

Answer (score 0):

Move your api call to asynctask or thread. You cannot use them in main ui thread.

Comment: I don't know how to do that, can you post a quick solution ?

Comment: Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25647881/android-asynctask-example-and-explanation

Answer (score -1):

First of all modify your php code like:

```
$id = htmlentities($_POST['Id']);
$name = htmlentities($_POST['Name']);
$email = htmlentities($_POST['Email']);
try{
    $con = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test", "root", "");
    $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}catch(Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
    die();
}
$query = "INSERT INTO record VALUES('?','?','?')";
$result = $con->prepare($query);
$result =  bindParam(?, $id);
$result =  bindParam(?, $name);
$result =  bindParam(?, $email);
$finalresult = $con->execute($result);
```

Comment: Can you fix the SQL injection vuln too, or at least make note of it in your answer? As it stands, this encourages the OP not to do anything about that. Also, I'm not sure echoing an error on a live service is a good idea - that might help an attacker understand the structure of the underlying tables, and aid their attack.

Comment: This code is giving me error on bindpram, saying call to uncdefined pram buildPram()