# how to parse JSON array (Language array )?

Tags: android

I want to fetch string values from a JSON-array and set it to a spinner in Android. How can I
 do this?

```
`{"languages":["English","Hindi","Punjabi","",""]} `languages":["English","Hindi","Punjabi","",""]}
```

Comment: what u have tried to parse current JSON String?

Comment: ...He asked the question here and he is expecting code ready to copy&paste ...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON Array (Not Json Object) in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18977144/how-to-parse-json-array-not-json-object-in-android)

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/30026152/3843374

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can parse your JSONARRAY like this**

```
if (jsonResultArry != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonResultArry.length(); i++) {

                try {

                JsonObject jsonPblm = jsonResultArry.getJSONObject(i);
                    pblmId = jsonPblm.getString("id");
                    ticketDate = jsonPblm.getString("ticket_date");
                    pblmName = jsonPblm.getString("description");

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
```