# NetworkOnMainThreadException while accessing a postgresql database

Tags: java, android, postgresql, exception

Well, trying to access a postgresql Database using Android, I got the following, very surprising Exception:

```
    org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Something unusual has occurred to cause the driver to fail. Please report this exception.
        at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:305)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:179)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:213)
        at org.pbdevelopement.cineapp.NetReader.getConnection(NetReader.java:42)
        at org.pbdevelopement.cineapp.MainActivity.getPersonalMovies(MainActivity.java:242)
        at org.pbdevelopement.cineapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:115)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6034)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1111)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2332)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2442)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:156)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1351)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5373)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1020)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:815)
    Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
        at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1151)
        at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:418)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getByName(InetAddress.java:305)
        at java.net.InetSocketAddress.(InetSocketAddress.java:105)
        at java.net.InetSocketAddress.(InetSocketAddress.java:90)
        at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.(PGStream.java:61)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:129)
        at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:65)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.(PgConnection.java:159)
        at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:415)
        at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:283)
        ... 18 more
```

I have no clue how to fix this, neither do I have a clue where to report it to... Does anybody have any ideas?

Comment: You can report Postgresql JDBC bugs here: https://jdbc.postgresql.org/community/mailinglist.html

Comment: Why this question is down-voted?

Comment: @bradimus what do you think, is this worth being reported? Or was I just to stupid to use their driver properly and don't deserve any better? ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you are trying to perform your database request through a network operation on the applications Main Thread. This throws the exception `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException` because every network operation in Android must be started in an own thread. Try to perform your Database request in `AsyncTask`.

[AsyncTask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25647881/android-asynctask-example-and-explanation)

Comment: Agreed.  Check your code that's listed in the stack trace:  `at org.pbdevelopement.cineapp.NetReader.getConnection(NetReader.java:42)
        at org.pbdevelopement.cineapp.MainActivity.getPersonalMovies(MainActivity.java:242)
        at org.pbdevelopement.cineapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:115)`  and implement somewhere besides your main thread.

Comment: Hm, sounds reasonable... Should it not throw a different exception though?