# Android additional threads and Looper

Tags: android, multithreading, looper

I am writing a Android application which reads data from a `SQLite Database` and then displays the data on a next screen. Whenever I was doing a query on the database I would get an error message that too much work is being done on the main thread.

I then put my query in a new Thread:

```
        (new Thread()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                Looper.prepare();
                try
                {
                    FPJobCardWizard data = dbHelperInstance.loadFPJobCardWizardFull(fitmentHash);
                    wState.fitmentItemSet(data.fitmentItemGet());
                } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
                Looper.loop();
            }
        }).start();
```

Now the gui/main thread is completing it's operation prior to the Query being complete and as a result the `data` variable is still empty. I read a few posts and the API documentation and it seems that I need to use a `Looper` (this seems to be the correct fix) but I have never used a Looper and cannot seem to get it to work.

Please can you check the code above and guide me in the right direction.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Use a handler to send the data to the UI thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the best choice here will be using an [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), as it will enables you to perform all the background work in a background thread, then when the result is generated it will apply it using the UI thread:

[image: AsyncTask life cycle]

So, as explained in the life cycle of `AsyncTask`, you can do all of your background work in the method `doInBackground()` and then do all of your UI work on the method `onPostExecute()` which will be executed after taking the result from `doInBackground()` method according to the life cycle, and to put your hands more on the `AsyncTask`, have a look at [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25647882/1638739) which provides the following example code:

```
public class AsyncTaskTestActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);  

        // This starts the AsyncTask
        // Doesn't need to be in onCreate()
        new MyTask().execute("my string paramater");
    }

    // Here is the AsyncTask class:
    //
    // AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result>.
    //    Params – the type (Object/primitive) you pass to the AsyncTask from .execute() 
    //    Progress – the type that gets passed to onProgressUpdate()
    //    Result – the type returns from doInBackground()
    // Any of them can be String, Integer, Void, etc. 

    private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

        // Runs in UI before background thread is called
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            // Do something like display a progress bar
        }

        // This is run in a background thread
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            // get the string from params, which is an array
            String myString = params[0];

            // Do something that takes a long time, for example:
            for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {

                // Do things

                // Call this to update your progress
                publishProgress(i);
            }

            return "this string is passed to onPostExecute";
        }

        // This is called from background thread but runs in UI
        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);

            // Do things like update the progress bar
        }

        // This runs in UI when background thread finishes
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            // Do things like hide the progress bar or change a TextView
        }
    }
}
```