# How can I return a List using AsyncTask?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am a novice Android programmer experimenting with AsyncTask and performing HTTP requests. My goal is to be able to perform the HTTP request using AsyncTask. My AsyncTask is below:

```
private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }
    @Override
    protected List<Book> doInBackground(String... params) {
        return Network.getBookData(params[0]);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
}
```

There is an error that says in the `doInBackground(String... params)` method, there is an attempt to use an incompatible return type. How can I fix this and still have the method return a `List<Book>`?

Comment: What's your problem?  There's no general problem with returning a list, just remember that the return value is passed into onPostExecute.  Its not returned from execute

Comment: read here first ->  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25647881/android-asynctask-example-and-explanation

Comment: Thanks Charuka. Updated question based on that post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either pass the `dataUrl` parameter into the constructor of the task or as the parameter for the task. The way you use the AsyncTask will change slightly depending on which you use.

As a constructor parameter:

```
new DownloadFilesTask(someUrl).execute(null);
```

As a task parameter

```
new DownloadFilesTask().execute(someUrl);
```

You should override `onPostExecute(List<Book> result)` in your Task class in order to do something with the HTTP results on the UI thread, such as rendering the Book objects in a list.

Comment: I tried both the constructor parameter and the task parameter and both don't work.

Comment: What do you mean they don't work? Is this a compilation or runtime error? Can you provide the code for `Network.getBookData`?

Comment: Ok. Here it is:

Comment: public static List<Book> getBookData(String dataUrl) {
        URL url = createUrl(dataUrl);
        String jsonResponse = null;
        try {
            jsonResponse = makeHttpRequest(url);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Problem making the HTTP request.", e);
        }

        // Extract relevant fields from the JSON response and create a list of {@link Earthquake}s
        List<Book> books = extractFeatureFromJson(jsonResponse);

        // Return the list of {@link Earthquake}s
        return books;
    }

Comment: I would recommend reading up on what the generic types on AsyncTask represent. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html The third type parameter is the return type of the `doInBackground` method, which right now is `Void`. So you should update your class definition to `public class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<Book>>`

Comment: That fixed the problem. Thanks a lot!!