# Load image with Glide to Google Maps Marker Inside Async Task

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-glide

I have been having a hard time trying to load url from `Google Map Api` into `Google Maps Marker` with `Async Task.` How do I correctly get this image loading library to load icons from google map api into the markers being shown in my custom map.

What is the best way to achieve this?

```
    public class GetNearbyPlaces extends AsyncTask<Object, String,String> {
          @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Object... objects) {
    mMap = (GoogleMap) objects[0];
        String url = (String) objects[1];
DownloadUrl downloadUrl = new DownloadUrl();
        try {
            googlePlaceData = downloadUrl.ReadTheURL(url);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return googlePlaceData;
    }

        private void DisplayNearbyPlaces(List<HashMap<String, String>> nearbyPlacesList){
            for (int i = 0; i<nearbyPlacesList.size(); i++){
                MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
                //load image icon from url
                String url = googleNearbyPlace.get("icon");
                loadMarkerIcon(url);

            }

        }
        private void loadMarkerIcon(final Marker marker, final String url) {
            Glide.with(context).load(url)
                    .asBitmap().fitCenter().into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
                @Override
                public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Bitmap bitmap, @Nullable Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {
                    BitmapDescriptor icon = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap);
                    marker.setIcon(icon);
                }

            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where is your AsyncTask doInBackground() method?

Comment: edited. please review

Comment: A little reading will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25647881/android-asynctask-example-and-explanation/25647882#25647882